# Does anyone know how to simulate keystrokes on a raspberry pi with code?

Tags: python, keyboard

I would like to replicate this code,  but on a raspberry pi.  It imports for windows.  Does anyone know of a library or anything that could help?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564851/how-to-generate-keyboard-events-in-python

Comment: i think that you want `how to generate keyboard events in linux`

Comment: @jsotola Probably.  That's  actually a good idea to research.

Comment: Have you tried the second answer's suggestion? `pyautogui` is supposed to be portable to Linux (which you're probably using on your Pi).